Is there a grammatical term for the ways in which 'to be' is used in these sentences?
The verb 'to be' is used differently in these two sentences:

I am a human.
I think therefore I am.

In the first sentence, the verb has a subject complement ('a human').
In the second there isn't one but 'to be' would mean something similar to 'to exist'.
My question is: is there a grammatical term for the different ways in which 'to be' is used here? My first guess was that in one it is an intransitive verb and the other is transitive but after looking at the definitions of those words, I've realised I'm wrong.

You were onto something in thinking transitive, to the extent that to be often serves to link subject with object, more than state anything deep like existence. That's to be as a "copular verb".

"am" is not an auxiliary verb in either sentence. It's an auxiliary when you use it in "I am going to the store".

@Barmar But "am" in both sentences exhibits the NICE properties of auxiliary verbs: Negation, Inversion, Code, and Emphasis. I am not a human; Am I a human?; I bet that you are (a human); I AM a human.

In the first sentence the verb is said to be a copular verb; in the second it is a verb of the most common sort, that is, a verb called a full verb or, also, a lexical verb.

(SOED)
I As full vb. 1 Have place in the realm of fact; exist; live. OE

AV Gen. 5:24 Enoch walked with God: and hee was not, for God tooke him.
DRYDEN Troy is no more.

II As copular vb. 7 (With n., adj., or (passing into sense 3) adj. phr.) Have the state or quality expressed by the predicate.

J. GRAINGER What is fame? an empty bubble.
GEO. ELIOT I'm a stranger in Florence.


"To be" as a full verb should be considered as being intransitive. Even as a copular verb (linking verb), it is considered to be intransitive (Citation Machine). However this information is not provided in the SOED (Shorter Oxford English Dictionary)

I don't know about the second 'am' being a full/lexical verb, which term you probably used to differentiate it from an auxiliary verb. In the first case, you can question it by saying "Are you (a human)?". In the second, you can also question it by saying "Are you?" Then, at least syntactically both are auxiliary verbs, are they not?

@JK2  There is no doubt that "be" has  meaning, and this meaning is "exist" (https://www.britannica.com/topic/cogito-ergo-sum); the only reason for using this term (full verb) is what can be extracted from the occurrence of the verb in the given clause where it is found; as you try to make sense of the words you realize that there is a meaning attached to the verb (and, of course, you realize as well that it is not used for the progressive nor the passive, thus it is not an auxiliary). This use of "to be" is not so often found today, except in a special form, that of the existential  (1/3)

@JK2 "there is/are/…" in which "there" has little meaning and perhaps blurs the connection with the meaning "exists" ("there is much doubt about that.": "about that, much doubt exists (is)"). // Elliptical sentences are common in dialogue; thus, "Are you?" for "Are you a human?" is just a case of ellipsis. In the case of "I think therefore I am", you should realize that when you pass from the affirmative form to the question form, the verb remains the same (simplistic consideration that one might forget, but convincing); (2/3)

@JK2 therefore, you can't have an auxiliary since you started with a full verb.  One more thing to bear in mind, and that is in keeping with what I said above, a question such as "Are you?" in the context of Descartes little dictum is only theoretical language; true, it is logical, but it has no incidence in English (no more than in French); one would say, rather, "Do you exist?". (3/3)

Well, if the second "am" is a full/lexical verb, why can't the second sentence be "...therefore I do be" when emphasized and "...therefore I don't be" when negated?

@JK2 You can't because do-support is not used for lexical "be" as a matter of exception ; do-support is not used for copular "be", yet, in imperatives, it is possible to use it, and that is anothere exception ("Do be quiet!").

Auxiliaries (do, be, have; and modals) all exhibit the NICE properties (Negation, Inversion, Code, Emphasis). In contrast, non-auxiliary verbs (aka, main/full/lexical verbs) don't. Be, like other auxiliaries, exhibits the NICE properties with or without a following main/full/lexical verb. So it's only reasonable to think of be as an auxiliary even when not followed by a main/full/lexical verb, isn't it?

@JK2 As an auxiliary, it follows NICE, true, but even in this auxiliary function there is an exception ("Don't be tellling your bawdy stories when she is visiting us." ). Why could there not be an exception in the case of the full verb? Do you mean to say that you can't conceive "be" as a full verb in the second sentence, and that you think,  instead, that it is an auxiliary? But then, supposing you are right, in what process is it an auxiliary?

You seem to think that be in your Don't be telling... doesn't follow NICE in that it is not negated. But this is not "an exception." Auxiliaries are negated only when they are the first verb in a finite clause. Therefore, the first verb negated in a finite clause is always an auxiliary, whereas no first main/full/lexical verb in a finite clause can be negated.

@JK2 "Be" is negated: "do not be …". E in NICE says that "auxiliaries can be used for emphasis", so I think it is an exception because you can't use "be", an auxiliary, for emphasis ("Be not telling lies." is not said); you normally use do-support, whereas for auxiliaries you can't ("You do must have …, They do could tell …, etc", all such  forms are banished from the language, so to speak).

In do not be..., it's not be but do that is negated. So I don't know what you're talking about. *Be not telling lies is ungrammatical, not because you can't use auxiliary be for emphasis, but because be cannot be the first auxiliary in the negative imperative (you'd need do for that: Don't be telling lies).

@JK2 I can understand that "do not" is a negation of "do", but the result is also a negation of "be" because the person has been told to "not be telling lies". Do-support is a way to negate full verbs, and exceptionally other verbs.

No, we're not talking about semantics but syntax when we're talking about what is being negated.

@JK2 Don't you think that the time when we should have gone on to chat is long overdue?

@JK2 One more question I might put to the incessant reflective activity of your inquiring mind: what do you think of the expression "So be it"?

@JK2 I hope I didn't smother your enthusiasm, or should we say, something else rather than "enthusiasm" …

I've said enough on the issue of whether be is an auxiliary or not, and you've not been able to persuade me into thinking that it is not. So be it is a fixed phrase, so it's not related to the issue.

@JK2 If you change your mind or find something convincing to prove your claim, I'd appreciate your letting me know. Bye for now.
